# GitAhead: how to set correct file encoding in diff view?

Tags: encoding, view, character-encoding, diff, gitahead

GitAhead displays cyrillic symbols incorrectly.

I checked both menu and config dialog and dont found any param to set encoding type.
[incorrect encoding display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyYRR.png)

Sample of incorrect encoding:

> `"Р“Р»РѕМЃРєР°СЏ РєСѓМЃР·РґСЂР° С€С‚РµМЃРєРѕ Р±СѓРґР»Р°РЅСѓМЃР»Р° Р±РѕМЃРєСЂР°"`

OS: Windows 10
GitAhead: v2.6.1 (fe29eca)

Comment: If you haven't found any parameter to set the encoding of your choice, you might want to report this directly to the GitAhead development team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding setting is under Tools > Options... > Diff > Character Encoding. It should default to you system locale's default encoding.